# The $* issue has a major bug in it

Tags: perl

I have the following code in my perl script that is simply a `print` statement.  The `$*` is in quotes and I just want to print that, but it gives a fatal error.

```perl
print OUT4 "\texec su -c $0 $*\n\techo \"exec failed!\";
```

There is no way this should be a fatal error.  The error is `$* is no longer supported`.

I tried to print and I expected it to print the `$*` instead of an error.

Comment: I think you need to escape `$`. Try `print OUT4 "\texec su -c \$0 \$*\n\techo "exec failed!";`

Comment: Tip: You should avoid using global variables (`OUT4`) in favour of lexical variables: `open( my $OUT4, ... )`

Answer (score 3):

First of all,

```bash
su -c $0 $*
```

should be

```bash
su -c "$0" "$@"
```

(Yes, that's `$@` and not `$*`.)

What you had fails if there's a space in `$0` or in any of the arguments.

---

On to your question.

`$` has a special meaning in double-quoted string literals, so you need to escape it if you want it to include it in the string literally. Same for `"` when `"` is the delimiter.

```perl
print OUT4 "exec su -c \"\$0\" \"$@\"\necho 'exec failed!'\n";
```

I would write it as follows since it's far more readable:

```perl
say OUT4 q{exec su -c "$0" "$@"};
say OUT4 q{echo 'exec failed!'};
```

This would also work:

```perl
say OUT4 q{exec su -c "$0" "$@" || echo 'exec failed!'};
```